# Nifty Modal Transitions and animations with Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, css-transitions

Have any of you implemented Nifty Modal Transitions with Jquery Mobile? If so, please let know how to go about doing this.

http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/

Comment: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/custom-page-transitions-part-1/ and http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/custom-page-transitions-part-2/

Comment: Have a look at the articles Omar linked and then you can use the source CSS from the Nifty site to create your custom transitions.

Comment: Hi ezanker... I was able to integrate Nifty Modal Transitions to a Jquery Mobile Sample Page... take a look at it at http://apps.alfonsopolanco.com  but I couldn't figure out about integrating the right css rules to apply the transitions to a page like we have done before with animate.css using the attribute data-role="customTransition". If you have any idea.. please let me know

Comment: Hey Guys any ideas on how to get regular jquery mobile transitions with Nifty Transitions Effects... I was able get the modal effects with JQM but what I want is regular transitions using data-transition attribute. Thank you.

Comment: Any ideas on this folks? Thanks